# Do I need to call TCanvas.Refresh after RestoreDC?

Tags: delphi

I am maintaining some code that contains the following:

```
    Canvas.Refresh;
    SavedDC := SaveDC(Canvas.Handle);
    try
      // Paint Stuff to the Canvas
    finally
      RestoreDC(Canvas.Handle, SavedDC);
      Canvas.Refresh;
    end;
```

I have learned that TCanvas.Refresh is nothing like a component refresh.  It does not cause anything to paint, it just [invalidates the Font, Pen, and Brush of the canvas](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Graphics_TCanvas_Refresh.html).

I don't understand why you would call .Refresh before Saving the DC and then after restoring it back.  That seems to kind of defeat the purpose of the SaveDC/RestoreDC calls.

A more reasonable order for these calls seems to be:

```
  SaveDC(Canvas.Handle)
  Canvas.Refresh
  try
     // Do my painting
  finally
    RestoreDC(Canvas.Handle, SavedDC);
  end;
```

Since I have never seen or used the TCanvas.Refresh method I wanted to check and make sure I understood this correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an explanation - http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27786

Calling Refresh after RestoreDC guarantees synchronization between TCanvas state and underlying device context.

Not sure that calling Refresh before SaveDC is necessary in modern Windows versions, but where is nothing wrong in it.

I would recommend to leave the code as is.

Comment: It appears from the article I should be saving off the handle before calling refresh.  Of course it also says calling refresh first is only needed for windows 9x...